# CompareTo method in java acting weird

Tags: java

I have an issue with the `compareTo` method in java, this is the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < btFolder.size(); i++) {

        String g = btFolder.get(i).toString();

        String[] subf = g.split(splitchar);

        String s = subf[subf.length-1].toUpperCase();

        if(s.compareTo(bt.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
            return g; 
        }
    }
    return null; //not found!
```

this will not jump into the `if-statement`, it should because the `s` and `bt` variables are equal, I know because I've done my homework and debugged it. Just to figure out what the `compareTo` method return I wrote this piece of code:

```
        String g = btFolder.get(i).toString();

        String[] subf = g.split(splitchar);

        String s = subf[subf.length-1].toUpperCase();

        String btUp = bt.toUpperCase();

        int theSame = s.compareTo(btUp);

        if(theSame == 0) {
           putSharedPrefs("pathToBt", g); 
        }
        return null;
```

The variable `theSame` is 0, which means that `s` and `btUp` is equal. And still, `the if-statement` is never executed!

Why is this happening? Any good solutions to this?

**EDIT**

I've tried this too:

```
boolean equals = s.equalsIgnoreCase(bt);

        if(equals) {
            return g; 
        }
```

The `boolean` is `true`, but never excutes the `if-statement`, I should also mentioned that this is done inside a `thread`, but that should not cause any problem?

Comment: Why don't you use `String.equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `compareTo`?

Comment: because it's a bit sketchy to use it. I want the whole String to be exactly the same, in the same order and not apart of the string. This is really not the question why I use the `compareTo` it should work.

Comment: *"The variable theSame is 0, which means that s and btUp is equal. And still, the if-statement is never executed!"* => that's not possible. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: Why isn't that possible? the variable **is** 0 and in my if-statement I check if the variables is 0?

Comment: *"I should also mentioned that this is done inside a thread, but that should not cause any problem?"* It might be the reason. If you set the variable in one thread and reads if from another thread, you have no guarantee to read the written value without synchronization.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen If the variable really is 0, then the body of `if(var == 0) {...}` will be executed.

Comment: My debugger says that the variable is 0, I hope I can trust my debugger and the information that it gives to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this snippet

```
if(theSame == 0) {
       putSharedPrefs("pathToBt", g); 
}
```

if you can debug and check that `theSame` is `0` then please put a **sysout** and see whether its printed or not.

Since you are quite sure that if is not being executed; it seems the case that the code you are debugging and the code being executed are not same. This sometimes happens in eclipse when the build is not deployed and you are debugging new source with old executable.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(bt) {
    return g; 
}
```

I guess you can use compareTo however it does other things too...